# How can I calculate or think about the large number 32768^1049088?

Tags: big-numbers

I decided to ask myself how many different images my laptop's screen could display.  I came up with (number of colors)^(number of pixels) so assuming 32768 colors I'm trying to get my head around the number, but I have a feeling it's too big to actually calculate.

Am I right that it's too big to calculate?  If not, then how?  If so then how would you approach grasping the magnitude?

Update: I realized a simpler way to get the same number is 2^(number of bits of video RAM) or "all the possible configurations of video RAM" - correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: That’s roughly $10^{4.5\times10^6}$, which is a $1$ followed by four and a half million zeroes.

Comment: thanks, it's disturbing how much I forget from the days of going to school

Comment: 24-bit graphics allows for $2^{24} = 16777216$ colors, not $32768$.

Comment: thanks for the corrections - i'll think a little longer before posting next time.. i appreciate the help

Comment: However, the vast majority of these images will just be noise.

Comment: I think that means that there are more than $8*10^{7579366}$ and there are only $10^80$ atoms in the visible universe.

Comment: Yet it's easy to calculate the right-most digit!

Comment: Somewhere in that collection of images is a proof (or counterexample) to the Riemann hypothesis, all the unwritten music and unwritten books, pictures of distant planets, pictures of hypothetical planets and dictionaries of never spoken languages. You could find cures for diseases and the deepest secrets of every person alive. The only trouble is putting it all together.

Comment: Where do you get 1049088 pixels from?  That number looks like it probably has a typo in it somewhere, since it's $2^9\cdot 3 \cdot 683$, and 683 is unlikely to divide either the x or y resolution of your display - but $3\cdot 683=2049$, and so the original number is _also_ $2^9\cdot(2^{11}+1)$...

Answer (score 2):

Your original number is
$2^{15*2^{20}}
<2^{2^{24}}
< 10^{2^{21}}< 10^{3*10^6}
$
which is certainly computable
since it has less than
3,000,000 digits.

The new, larger number is
$2^{24*2^{20}}
<2^{2^{25}}
< 10^{2^{22}}< 10^{6*10^6}
$
which is still computable
since it has less than
6,000,000 digits.

Comment: I fixed a small typo in the MathJax (a pair of braces).  It is not true that $$2^{2^{24}} = 2^{8 \cdot 2^{21}} = (2^8)^{2^{21}} = 256^{2^{21}} < 10^{2^{21}}$$ as you claim. Also, technically, you are abusing the term "computable".

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that $24$ bit color allows $2^{24}$ colors in a pixel, you get $(2^{24})^{1049088}=2^{24\cdot 1049088}=2^{25178112}$  If you like powers of $10$ better, this is about $10^{25178112\cdot \log_{10}2}\approx 10^{7.58\cdot 10^6}$